# How can I get the lowest values in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection called product which has the following documents as seen below.

```
{
    "product" : "Milk",
    "barcode" : 12345,
    "price" : 100,
    "store" : "BestBuy"
},
{
    "product" : "Milk",
    "barcode" : 12345,
    "price" : 100,
    "store" : "WalMart"
},
{
    "product" : "Milk",
    "barcode" : 12345,
    "price" : 130,
    "store" : "Target"
},
{
    "product" : "Milk",
    "barcode" : 12345,
    "price" : 500,
    "store" : "Game"
}
```

I wish to query the collection  and only return documents that have the lowest price e.g

```
{ 
    product: "Milk",
    barcode: 12345, 
    price: 100, 
    store: "BestBuy"
}
{ 
    product: "Milk",
    barcode: 12345, 
    price: 100,
    store: "WalMart"
}
```

But when I run my aggregation query:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$match:{barcode:1234}},{$group: {_id:"$name", price:  {$min:"$price"} } }])
```

It only returns one document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents by "price". From there, you [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) them by "_id" in ascending order and use [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to return the first document which nothing other than the document with the minimum value.

```
db.products.aggregate([ 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$price", 
        "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } 
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }, 
    { "$limit": 1 } 
])
```

which produces something like:

```
{
    "_id" : 100,
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("574a161b17569e552e35edb5"),
            "product" : "Milk",
            "barcode" : 12345,
            "price" : 100,
            "store" : "BestBuy"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("574a161b17569e552e35edb6"),
            "product" : "Milk",
            "barcode" : 12345,
            "price" : 100,
            "store" : "WalMart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved my dilema. Question what is the purpose of $$Root?

Comment: $$ROOT returns the whole document. Useful when you need to have all fields available in the result set.

Comment: @logic I agree with you. But you can always `$push` only the fields you want for example let say "price"  using `$push: { "price": "$price" }`