# MongoDB all entries with maximum values in column

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the data

```
{"name" : "user1", age : 40 }
{"name" : "user2", age : 45 }
{"name" : "user3", age : 50 }
{"name" : "user4", age : 40 }
{"name" : "user5", age : 40 }
{"name" : "user6", age : 21 }
```

I want all rows having the maximum age.

Basically fetch all rows whose column value is maximum in the column.

SQL query : `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age = (SELECT max(age) FROM Person)`

How can I do the same in MongoDB ? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the lowest values in a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501925/how-can-i-get-the-lowest-values-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the aggregation framework like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$age", 
        "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } 
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 1 }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you explain what you are doing there ?

Comment: @sujithvm Please read my other [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37504155/3100115) for more details.